# Flutter turning wifi on/off

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I turn on/off WiFi programmatically in flutter?

Comment: i think that must be through writing platform-specific codes only

Answer (score 4):

wifi_iot: ^0.1.1 package use in pubspac

```
import 'package:wifi_iot/wifi_iot.dart';
    
...

RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Enable"),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      WiFiForIoTPlugin.setEnabled(true);
    });
  },
),
```

Comment: Is this still possible in Android 10+?

Comment: In Android Q (Android 10) you can't enable/disable wifi programmatically anymore. Use Settings Panel to toggle wifi connectivity:

Comment: WiFiForIoTPlugin.setEnabled(true,
                  shouldOpenSettings: true);